# poetry show command - what do the red listed packages mean?

Tags: python, python-poetry

When I run `poetry show` - most of my packages are blue but a few are red? What do these two colors mean?

I think red means the package is not @latest ?

Comment: Source code of `poetry show`, in case it helps: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/blob/master/src/poetry/console/commands/show.py

Answer (score 12):

- **Black:** Not required package
- **Red:** Not installed / It needs an immediate semver-compliant upgrade
- **Yellow:** It needs an upgrade but has potential BC breaks so is not urgent
- **Green:** Already latest

Comment: What does "BC" mean ?

Comment: @yucer breaking change I guess

Comment: Searched but above color scheme definitions not found in Poetry doc.

Comment: @Leo They are in source code as stated in other comments: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/blob/master/src/poetry/console/commands/show.py

Answer (score -1):

Yes, red indicates that you have an outdated package and blue is up to date

Comment: And blue is what?

Comment: And you can just run a `poetry update <package-name>` or `poetry update <package-name@latest>` ??

Comment: as stated in another comment, red means not installed https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/blob/master/src/poetry/console/commands/show.py#L312